# How to find person by name and import his passwords

Tags: excel, function

I have 2 spreadsheets. In second I have users and passwords in this order:

Name | Surname | Mail | Password | PC Login | PC Password

I want to enter name or surname in cell. Then after press enter, I want to excel import from 2 spreadsheet to 1 spreadsheet passwords from mail and pc

Which function should I use? How to do it?

Comment: [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) the link has instructions on its use.

Answer (score 0):

`VLookUp` is the quick answer.

Are the sheets in separate workbooks (`.xlsx` files)? If so you can still do a `VLookUp`. Open both workbooks, begin writing the `VLookUp` formula, and when asked for a range click over to the 2nd workbook and it will automatically create the connection, in the format `=[Foo.xlsx]"Sheet 1"!A1`. This requires both spreadsheets to be in the same folder - it won't work if they're hosted on Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Excel, vLookup or Index + Match would probably do the trick.

On the sheet you're displaying the lookup values:
A2: Name, B2: Surname

(Cell C2 (PW)|D2(PC) =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2 ..SurName..,Staff!B:F, 3 | 5  (Password/PC Password),FALSE),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2 ...Name...,Staff!A:F,4 | 6 (Password/PC Password,FALSE))

when someone types a value in A2, if (Name) it will pull the info from sheet X.  If they enter a value in the surname, it will pull using that.

To get it to where only one cell is used and it is either the name or surname, you would use just change the $B2 to $A2 in the first VLOOKUP.